# Filtering and selecting by label

Tags: prometheus, promql

How to obtain the most recent metric, by selecting and ignoring labels.

For example, the following query:

`last_over_time(application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""}[1h])`

Returns the following items:

`application_version{id="tmo4xpmj", instance="Test", job="application", site="NYC", version="21.1.3"} 1`

`application_version{id="tmo4xpmj", instance="Test", job="application", site="NYC", version="21.0.2"} 1`

I would like to retrieve a single record to use the last “version” label. In the example above, I would like to get the version “21.1.3” to display it in a Grafana Dashboard.

I tried with the keyword “without” without no success.

I think some people must have encountered the same problem with the “go_info” metric

Thanks,

Rémy

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of this queries:

```
max_over_time(
 timestamp(
  application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""}
 )[1h:]
) == scalar(
 max(
  max_over_time(
   timestamp(
    application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""}
   )[1h:]
  )
 )
)
```

```
max_over_time(
 timestamp(
  application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""}
 )[1h:]
)
== on() group_left() 
max(
 max_over_time(
  timestamp(
   application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""}
  )[1h:]
 )
)
```

Both of them return only metric where timestamp of last present value is the biggest.

It will return a single result. Even if metrics seems to be scraped near each other (withing same window of staleness), those queries will still select one with the biggest timestamp.

If you anticipate that you'll have a need for multiple results based on distinction in some label, use the latter one. Once you'll need multiple results, you could convert `max` to `max by`, and add needed labels to `on()` clause.

And if you are not happy with the fact, that both of my queries return timestamp instead of 1 as value, you can add in the beginning of either of them

```
application_version{site="NYC", instance="Test", id!=""} and
```

or wrap with `(` and `) * 0 + 1`.

> I think some people must have encountered the same problem with the “go_info” metric

I believe conventional wisdom, is to use query like `go_build_info`, without any `last_over_time`. This way you'll always have actual data, any if nothing is returned - it means something went terribly wrong.