# I'd like to send a free text String to Grafana via statsD and Prometheus

Tags: grafana, statsd

There are many statsD metrics. Some count slow producer events, slow consumer events and exception events. For these types of metric I'd like to send a text string which is displayed in Grafana next to the metric count. Like a log. Instead of reading a log file, the metric is like a tweet i.e. a free text statsD string with some max length that describes the slow producer, consumer or exception events.

It looks like I can send a statsD `set` with some free text. Then it's captured by Prometheus and sent to Grafana.

Is there a better way to achieve this "tweeting" of metric descriptions?

Comment: Sounds like misuse of Prometheus. Prometheus is not very happy with high cardinality labels, and it sounds like you put some freehand text into your labels.

Comment: If all you want is to show some notes on panel, wouldn't annotations suffice?

Comment: When there's an exception event counter I also want to send a text string on what the event is. For example "null pointer exception". The string is displayed in a table next to the exception counter... but I don't want to have to have different counters for every exception type. Just 1 counter for all exceptions, and a free text string with a label yeah.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. If you have different label values, Prometheus will represent it internally as different time series. And if you'll have multiple errors near each other, you'll have to deal with metric "staleness" (it can be done though, it's just wouldn't be straghtforward, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76590952/21363224) is somewhat similar answer, but you'll need `max by(last_error)` and `without(last_error)` near `==` instead of `on()`).